# Can we use the polar form of Cauchy-Riemann equations at zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Suppose that we want to show that the function

$$f(z)=\begin{cases}
\frac{z^5}{|z|^4},z\neq0\\
0,z=0
\end{cases}$$

satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations at $z=0$. We see that

$$\frac{z^5}{|z|^4}=\frac{z^3}{\bar z^2}=\frac{x^3+3x^2iy-3xy^2-iy^3}{x^2-2ixy-y^2}$$

So finding $u$ and $v$ is slightly hard.

But the polar form of $\frac{z^5}{|z|^4}$ is $re^{5i\theta}=r\cos5\theta+ir\sin5\theta$. So

$$ru_r=r\cos5\theta,v_\theta=5r\cos5\theta\\
rv_r=r\sin5\theta,-u_\theta=5r\sin5\theta$$

But $\theta$ is undefined at $z=0$. So I want to know if we can put $r=0$ and conclude that

$$ru_r=v_\theta,rv_r=-u_\theta?$$

So at all what can we do here?

Comment: Good question! The $\frac1r$ in the polar C-R equations becomes undefined as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that$$u(x,y)=\operatorname{Re}\bigl(f(x+yi)\bigr)=\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{(x+yi)^5}{|x+yi|^2}\right)$$(if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$). Therefore, $x\neq0\implies u(x,0)=\operatorname{Re}x=x$ and so $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,0)=1$. On the other hand, $y\neq0\implies u(0,y)=\operatorname{Re}(yi)=0$ and so $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$.

Using the same approach, it is easy to see that $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(0,0)=0$ and that $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(0,0)=1$. Therefore, $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry to ask you, But I want to know if you are agree with other answer to my question?

Comment: @user547800 I don't agree, because using the polar form of the Cauchy-Riemann equations assume that $r>0$.

Comment: I mean Christian Blatter's answer? Could you please see my comment to his answer?

Comment: @user547800 I disagree with his answer. In fact, the function from your question is a conter-example to his assertion. Another example would be $f(z)=\sqrt{|\operatorname{Re}(z).\operatorname{Im}(z)|}$.